# Problems in website data in database design

Tags: web, client

I need to create a website that will display some data fetched from mysql database.
When executing it on my local machine it works correctly.
What i need to know is how do i do this same when websites is moved to the server.I mean i cannot go and create a database for my website on the server.How is this done?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your web host or web server should provide you with PHPmyadmin which allows you to create a database. So if you login on your web host, server you should be able to see phpmyadmin, if you click on that then u are allowed to create a database for your website in your webserver.